# How to performance tune AJAX heavy application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, memcached

I'm developing kind of image/profile search application, that is based almost exclusively on AJAX. Main page basically displays profile images and allows user to filter/search and paginate through them.

Pagination works when user scrolls, so the **interface has to be very very fast**. There will be only 6 (maybe 9, but definitely not more) images displayed on the main page, so users will scroll a lot. I'm currently using very simple JS cache to store results of all the requests in case user decides to go back ... in that case, I simply pull everything out of the cache instead of querying the server.

## Client cache

One option that I thought of is to pre-load say 10 pages in front and store them in the cache.

But **my biggest issue is filtering/searching**, since that completely changes the type of query that goes to the server. My filters aren't very complex, only around 6-7 string/number/enum attributes.

Now if I wanted to do all the filtering in the cache, I would have to duplicate all the search logic and fetch all the data from the server (not just the data I'm displaying), so I could filter the results on client side.

Here raises a question, should I make the cache somehow persistent? Store it into a cookie maybe?

## Server cache?

One suggestion might be to **use memcached on the server and just store everything there.** I'm definiely going to cache away all the results I can, but that doesn't save the server from handling loads and loads of AJAX requests.

I'm developing this application on Rails 3, and even though I love it, I wouldn't say it's the fastest thing in the world. **Another option that this gives me is to create separate Rack/Sinatra application to handle only the AJAX requests.** By this I mean requests from the main query, not all AJAX.

## S3 for images?

Big part of this application are images, even though they're mostly small thumbnails (unless user wants to display it bigger).

At the moment, I don't have problems with bandwidth. My VPS host provides me with 200GB, which should be more than enough (I hope). The problem is loading speed. Would it help if I uploaded all the images to S3 and load them from there, or is this worth doing only for larger files? I'm going to load **a lot of 100x150px images**, which are generally under 50kB.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples). It has an interesting idea of only building the list as users scroll down but then removing the list as the users scroll out of that range.